# Serverless Next.js on AWS Lambda

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, next.js

As I've been reading about Next.js' recent features around [serverless](https://nextjs.org/docs#serverless-deployment), I have a few questions in ensuring it meets our needs. As I understand it, AWS Lambda has the following [limitations](https://hackernoon.com/lessons-learned-a-year-of-going-fully-serverless-in-production-3d7e0d72213f) and I’m unsure on how to resolve them using best practices with Next.js:

1. `52mb` limit size with AWS Lambda. Although it would be hard to imagine our application going above this limit, I’m worried that with a large node_modules directory, this could, potentially, be an issue in the future. What are some ways to go around this?
2. Performance and cold starts. I understand that if the Lambda function is not periodically executed, the boot up time to execute the Lambda service can range between `600`-`2500ms`. This is not acceptable for a user facing client application. What are some ways to mitigate this?
3. Hydrating redux state. Any best practices for rendering redux state as part of the initial payload?
4. CDN. Given that these templates are generated at runtime, are there any simple/scalable ways to offer them over CDN (e.g. Cloudfront)?
5. Intelligent template caching. We have cases where certain elements are hidden if the user is not logged in. We want these to be the only pages that are indexed by search engines (ie SEO). That said, if we cache our templates, how can we ensure that we don’t serve incorrect templates to these engines (e.g. ones that include sensitive data for users that are logged in in any given page).

Comment: You should google these things, there is no exact answer to any of the questions.  Here you can study cloud front caching, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html Most of these can be done, but they are like up to you to engineer.

Comment: For `2` you can have a look at https://hackernoon.com/im-afraid-you-re-thinking-about-aws-lambda-cold-starts-all-wrong-7d907f278a4f - you can run regular invokes on your functions (even triggering some concurrent executions), to keep functions warm and avoid too many cold starts on your users.